# move semantics in constructor in return statement

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, elision

I know that when returning a local in order to keep RVO we should allow the compiler to perform move elision by returning a value like so

```
std::vector<double> some_func(){
    std::vector<double> my_vector;
    //do something
    return my_vector;
}
```

rather than

```
std::vector<double> some_func(){
    std::vector<double> my_vector;
    //do something
    return std::move(my_vector);
}
```

However, if we are constructing an object in a return statement, do uses of `std::move` in the constructor either help, hinder, or do nothing to get efficiency or get in the compilers way?

As an example consider these two implementations

```
std::pair<std::vector<double>,std::vector<double> > some_func()
    std::vector<double> my_vec_a;
    std::vector<double> my_vec_b;
    //do something
    return std::make_pair(my_vec_a,my_vec_b);
}
```

and

```
std::pair<std::vector<double>,std::vector<double> > some_func()
    std::vector<double> my_vec_a;
    std::vector<double> my_vec_b;
    //do something
    return std::make_pair(std::move(my_vec_a),std::move(my_vec_b));
}
```

So

1. In the first, will the compiler recognise that `my_vec_a` and `my_vec_b` will go out of scope and optimise the construction in the return statement?
2. If so will the use of `std::move` in the second prevent that optimisation?
3. Or will the second option be more efficient?

Comment: The answer depends on the compiler and its optimization settings. Note that gcc 11.1 with -O1 produces exactly identical assembly even for your first two snippets. You can easily check it in your browser, here https://godbolt.org/

Comment: @DarioP Cool site, thanks. Yeah it all gives the same assembly when optimised. My main fear was getting in the way of elision somehow.

Comment: @user3353819 How do you figure that it gives the same assembly? Both compilers are able to better optimize for the case where `std::move` is used. https://godbolt.org/z/sa9ocnPvG.
NRVO doesn't apply in this case as according to cppreference `which is of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type. This variant of copy elision is known as NRVO`. So, I'd prefer using `std::move` here.

Comment: @Staz Ah, I didn't wrap it in a `foo()` function so didn't see the upstream optimisation for  the whole of the return, so was just looking at changes in the assembly for `some_func`. Yep, ok, understood, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is more efficient:

```
std::pair<std::vector<double>,std::vector<double> > some_func() { 
    std::vector<double> my_vec_a;
    std::vector<double> my_vec_b;
    //do something
    return std::make_pair(std::move(my_vec_a),std::move(my_vec_b));
}
```

without the calls to `std::move` the two vectors will be copied.

The problem, however, isn't the actual return. It's that the two vectors in the pair being constructed are being constructed from lvalues; the compiler can't choose to use a move-constructor there without you explicitly telling it to via `std::move`.

Comment: There is another option: `std::pair<std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>> r;\nauto& [my_vec_a, my_vec_b] = r; \n//do something\nreturn r;`